# How Do I Use IMPORTXML For Hundreds of URL's?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Basically I have a row of 300+ URL's.

I need to extract the title beside each URL in the next column.

So I tried this:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//title")
```

and dragged it down to A300+ - it works, the issue is that it's calling way too many things and google is telling me that, I waited till the last 2 and then refreshed the page by accident and all over again.

I also tried:

```
={IMPORTXML(A1,"//title");IMPORTXML(A327,"//title")}
```

as someone else suggested and it's still loading (same issue).

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: unfortunately, not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, [IMPORTXML does not support ARRAYFORMULA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59908517/15384825). Also, when there are hundred of cells that contain IMPORTXML function, the results from this function may reload given there will be multiple requests of IMPORTXML.

**ALTERNATIVE OPTION**:

You can try this sample by [creating a bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script) (see below) in a spreadsheet file that will give you a custom menu:

[image]

This script will use [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) instead of IMPORTXML function to get the titles of the URLs.

**SAMPLE SCRIPT:**

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('URL titles')
      .addItem('Show URL titles on Column B', 'processTitles')
      .addToUi();
}

function processTitles(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = ss.getDataRange().getLastRow();
  var url;
  
  for(row=1; row<= lastRow; row++){ //Script will start getting URL from A1 and beyond
    if(ss.getRange("B"+row).getValue() == ""){
        try{
          url = ss.getRange("A"+row).getValue();
          var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
          ss.getRange("B"+row).setValue(response.match('<title>(.*?)</title>')[1])
          Logger.log(response.match('<title>(.*?)</title>')[1].toString());
          continue;
        }catch(e){
          ss.getRange("B"+row).setValue(response.match('title="(.*?)"')[1]);
          Logger.log(response.match('title="(.*?)"')[1].toString());
          continue;
        }
    }else{
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

> The custom menu ***Show URL titles on Column B*** will automate the
> scraping of URL titles by reading the HTML content of the URL and will look for the `<title></title>` tags OR `title=""` using the [match()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) method. I've used the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12030612 as a reference for this.

**SAMPLE RESULT:**

> *Sample sheet file with URLs on Column A:*

[image]

> Once you run the script from the editor, go back to your spreadsheet file and click the custom menu `Show URL titles on Column B`

> Here's the result after running the custom menu:

[image]